# Dreamcast Pi Emulation

Tags: emulation

I have read some articles lately that state folks have gotten Reicast (a Dreamcast emulator) to run pretty well on a Pi 2. However, I see only windows and android builds of Reicast. Does anyone know how to achieve this? My actual goal is Dreamcast emulation on a Pi, so alternate solutions are welcome. For example, could Windows 10 IoT be run on the Pi, and then standard windows emulators be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, could Windows 10 IoT be run on the Pi, and then standard windows emulators be used?

No.  Windows 10 IOT isn't the same thing you'll find on a desktop, laptop, nor even a tablet. It does not come with a GUI, and since it's running on an arm7 processor, it will not run standard Windows x86 applications.

You can find the RPi's Reicast branch [here](https://github.com/reicast/reicast-emulator/tree/skmp/rapi2), but from my quick Googling, it doesn't appear [to work](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=100076) particularly [well](https://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/31roi6/dreamcast_emulation_on_the_raspberry_pi_2_reicast/).  Apparently, the RPi just isn't powerful enough.